# Javascript array parsing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var usersRows = [];
connection.query('SELECT * from users', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            usersRows.push(row);
        });
        console.log(usersRows);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.' + err);
    }
});
```

It returned to me:

```
var usersRows = [ [ RowDataPacket { id: 1, name: 'sall  brwon', number: '+99999999\r\n' } ] ];
```

I need to parse this and remove `rowdatapacket`; I need result like this:

```
userRows = { id: 1, name: 'my name is', number: '+999999\r\n' };
```

Comment: i cant find any solution... why so aggressive :(

Comment: for some reason, my comment has been erased... so the comment was: "and what have you tried?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
userRows = RowDataPacket;
```

Comment: RowDataPacket is not defined

Comment: how is it not defined ? from what i see on your post its value is { id: 1, name: 'sall  brwon', number: '+99999999\r\n'}

Comment: @Yokowasis: i need you, please help me.

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal why ? can't you just pm me ?

Comment: i got json from db with RowDataPacket. how to remove it?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get rid of RowDataPacket's array and save it in yours you can also use this:

`usersRows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `JSON.stringify(rows)`

Comment: That will return a string, when the OP is looking for the object.  Plus, it's pretty costly to do this, compared to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Was unable to understand and implement the accepted the answer.
Hence, tried the long way out according the results I was getting.

Am using "mysql": "2.13.0" and saw that the this library returned array of array out of which:

```
Index 0 had array of RowDataPackets 
Index 1 had other mysql related information.
```

Please find the code below:

```
var userDataList = [];
//Get only the rowdatapackets array which is at position 0
var usersRows = data[0];
//Loop around the data and parse as required
for (var i = 0; i < usersRows.length; i++) {
   var userData = {};
   //Parse the data if required else just
   userData.name = userRows.firstName + userRows.lastName;
   userDataList.push(userData);
}
```

If no parsing is required and you just want the data as is, you could use the solution like mentioned in link [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)
Have not tried it but could be tweaked and worked out.

There should be simpler way to do it but as a novice I found the above way server the purpose. Do comment in case of better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`RowDataPacket` is the class name of the object that contains the fields.

The console.log() result `[ [ RowDataPacket { id: 1, name: 'sall  brwon', number: '+99999999\r\n' } ] ]` should be read as "an array of one item, containing and array of one item, containing an object of class RowDataPacket with fields id, name, and number"